# Combinatorial Summation $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} (k-n)\binom{2n}{k}$

Tags: co.combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

For a particular problem, I reached until this point where eventually I have to prove this summation

$$
\frac{1}{n} \left ( \binom{2n}{n+1} + 2\binom{2n}{n+2} + 3\binom{2n}{n+3} + \dots + n\binom{2n}{2n} \right ) = \frac{1}{2}\binom{2n}{n}
$$

I've tried to form a differentiating function that would result in this but no luck with that.

Comment: Maybe it can be proved by induction on $n$?  Iterating the recursion 
${x \choose y} = {x-1 \choose y-1} + {x-1 \choose y}$ we get
${x \choose y} = {x-2 \choose y-2} + 2 {x-2 \choose y-1} + {x-2 \choose y}$.
Apply this to each term $(k-n) {2n \choose k}$ to get something very close to
the sum for $n-1$.

Comment: This smells like a homework question, which is not what this site is for. You could try asking at math.stackexchange.com, but in order for that to be well received, you will show that you have put in some serious effort first (describe what you have tried in detail etc.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The left hand side can be rewritten as
\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=0}^n\left(1-\frac{j}{n}\right)\binom{2n}{j}
&=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{2n}{j}-\sum_{j=0}^n\frac{j}{n}\binom{2n}{j}\\[6pt]
&=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{2n}{j}-2\sum_{j=1}^n\binom{2n-1}{j-1}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{2^{2n}+\binom{2n}{n}}{2}-2^{2n-1}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{1}{2}\binom{2n}{n}.
\end{align*}
Done.